# Using {% include 'includes/some.html' %} in django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I have a template as under:-

```
<div class= "comment-form m-2">
{% include "includes/comment_reply_form.html" %}</div>
```

If the user is authenticated then the html shows the form. However if the user is not logged in I want to show a Login button. I am handling the same by the following javascript.

```
$(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      if (user_is_authenticated === false) {
          $(".comment-form").html('{% include "includes/reply.html" %}');
      $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
      }

      else {
        $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
      }

});
```

But, instead of including the html in from reply.html, it is showing {% include "includes/reply.html" %} in the webpage. There is no problem with the javascript and if I add

```
<p> You need to Login </p>
```

in the following line. It works fine :-

```
 $(".comment-form").html('{% include "includes/reply.html" %}');
```

But since I need more options in my reply.html I want to add it as includes. I have tried using the escape character "/" in front of { but it didn't help.

Comment: Well the problem with this is: if the `{% include ... %}` renders a quote (`'`), then the string stops (according to JavaScript), so then we are in real trouble.

Comment: But it is showing {% include "includes/reply.html" %}  in the html, but html is not picking it up as a django template may be javascript is adding this as 
"{% include "includes/reply.html" %} "

Comment: Is this JavaScript *in* the template, or a "static" .js file. Django templates are rendered *at server side*, so at the client, the `{% include ... %}` has no meaning at all...

Comment: it is in my base.js file. And as I have mentioned if I replace include statement with a simple paragraph tag in my javascript it works fine.

Comment: of course it works fine, since, as said, the `base.js` is not *interpreted* by the Django engine. The *client* sees this `{% include %}` tag, and thus will not replace it, since a browser can not read Django template language (and even if it could, it has no access to the templates, files, models, views, etc.)

Comment: Ohhh. So I have to look for some other way .... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

not familiar but try

```
<div class= "comment-form m-2">
<script>
document.write('{% include "includes/comment_reply_form.html" %}')
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: The first template works fine, because it is in the html. 
The problem is when I am trying to add some other include statement using javascript.

Comment: Maybe you cannot do it dynamically trough javascript, try some server side commands maybe or do some bad workaround like include it in a hidden div element and then just unhide it...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the value from include in your javascript function just put it in the html with with display = none for example

```
<div id="comment-reply-form-template">
  {% include "includes/comment_reply_form.html" %}
```

Then in your javascript you can always clone the already rendered form when you need to...

Or you could make a custom template tag that will print the html in javascript string style with a bunch of '' + '' + ''

or prehaps look into the new es6 template strings 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

I think would work like

```
`{% include "includes/comment_reply_form.html" %}`
```

using the **`** character